# Trying to draft custom email body in outlook from excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, automation, outlook

I'm trying to learn how to use Excel/VBA to automate as much of the below workflow as I can:

1. I receive an email from a manager notifying me that an employee has Covid. This initial notification is not standardized
2. I manually enter the information (employee name, their state, company, test date, test results, etc) into a spreadsheet. Sometimes certain cells information are left blank if they are not provided in #1
3. I REPLY ALL to original email. I use a template and edit based on the information I've entered into the spreadsheet (for instance, certain states have different guidelines) and attach PDFs depending on the company. I may also ask for missing information

**My goal is to:**
Be able to press a button in excel to draft an email body  with information I've entered into spreadsheet. A combination of "mad lib" and "if *this* then *that*". If specific cells are blank, Id want the email to include what information i still need. I only send this specific email once, but I have to do it again every time there is a new Covid case.

**My restrictions are:**
Multiple people use this same workflow and spreadsheet, so ideally it would be simple for coworkers. I do not want excel to automatically send the email without the user reviewing it first.
I am very new to VBA, but am learning Python.
I cannot download anything on my work computer.

Thank you so much!